# Incorrect image dimensions in android when using Bitmap

Tags: android

I have.png image file stored as a resource in my android application. 
In my code, i am allocationg new Bitmap instance from that image as follow:

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imgName);
```

But when I read the image dimensions from the Bitmap object using getWight() and getHeight() methods,

```
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();
```

I am getting different results from the original image... Can some one explain me what am I missing, and how can I retreive the image size?

(My project is complied with android 2.2 - API 8)

Edit:
Ok - found out how to get the real dimensions:
setting `inJustDecodeBounds` property of the `BitmapFactory.Options` class to true as follow:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imgName, options);
    width = options.outWidth;
    height = options.outHeight;
```

The problem now is that the decoder returns null when we send `Options` argument, so I need to decode again like I did before (without `Options` argument...) to retrieve `Bitmap` instance -bizarre, isnt it?

Answer (score 13):

To get exact resource image use:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new Options();
    o.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap watermark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id, o);
```

This turns off the automatic screen density scaling.

Update:
I'm sure you realized this by now, but inJustDecodeBounds does just that, it finds the dimensions.  You will not get an image.  That option is generally for doing custom scaling.  You end up calling decodeResource twice, the second time setting:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

and making any adjustments to the options based on your:

```
width = options.outWidth;
height = options.outHeight;
```

Comment: Might not be what the OP was looking for, but it sure helped me a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Android scales your image for different densities (in a way for different screen resolutions and sizes). Place a separate copy of  your image  in drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi , drawable folders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you know if there is a way to get the "real" image size?

Comment: @ET easiest way is hardcoding it.  Anyway you will know the size of the image you have putted into the drawable folder. frankly i haven't tried to get real size

Comment: I cant use this solutions since the pictures are pretty dynamic, and they may be retrieved from web service in the future. Besides - I have lots of images :)

Comment: I'm wanting to do the same. It's a serious shortcoming to not be able to retrieve the source values of a bitmap. Considering this information is available to Android when loading a bitmap, it would be an easy addition to expose these values in the bitmap class.